# View is shrinked when using KeyboardAvoidingView and multiple flat lists in react native

Tags: react-native, textfield, react-native-flatlist

[image: video differences]

I've recently bumped into a problem and need some help.

I've a simple screen with KeyboardAvoidingView, inside there is text input + 2 flat lists
My initial idea is to have flatlists to take 45 % of the screen and it could be scrollable.

It works well on iOS but on android for some reason view shrinks.

Adding small reproducible code for the issues

```js
const RandomTest: React.FC<NavigationProps> = ({ navigation }) => {
    const data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15];
    return (
        <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'padding' : undefined} style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            <View style={{ flex: 0.1 }}>
                <TextInput
                    style={{ flex: 0.7, borderWidth: 1, borderColor: AppColors.green, borderRadius: 10 }}
                    placeholder="Placeholder"
                    value={'random'}
                    onChangeText={(input) => {}}
                />
            </View>
            <View style={{ flex: 0.45 }}>
                <FlatList
                    style={styles.flatList}
                    contentContainerStyle={{ alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'flex-end' }}
                    data={data}
                    nestedScrollEnabled={true}
                    renderItem={({ item }) => (
                        <View style={{ height: 50 }}>
                            <Text>Test</Text>
                        </View>
                    )}
                />
            </View>

            <View style={{ flex: 0.45 }}>
                <FlatList
                    style={styles.flatList}
                    contentContainerStyle={{ alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'flex-end' }}
                    data={data}
                    nestedScrollEnabled={true}
                    renderItem={({ item }) => (
                        <View style={{ height: 50 }}>
                            <Text>test[![enter image description here][1]][1]</Text>
                        </View>
                    )}
                />
            </View>
        </KeyboardAvoidingView>
    );
};
```

adding video here

Comment: You give iOS a behavior of padding and allow android to have the default behavior. Have you tried using 'padding'  or 'margin' for the `behavior` prop on the KeyboardAvoidingView?

Comment: @PhantomSpooks yeah indeed, I've tried all different behaviors, didn't help

Answer (score 0):

You must add additional styles to the container within the `KeyboardAvoidingView`, please look at the following code:

```js
<KeyboardAvoidingView
  style={{ flex: 1 }}
  contentContainerStyle={{
    flex: 1,
    flexShrink: 0, // <== this one
  }}
```

Comment: @AsMartynas, If you think it doesn't work. Please leave a snack expo and I'll help you for sure.

Answer (score 0):

The **KeyboardAvoidingView will always collapse the children for iOS when we have behaviour property**, and when using flex:1 as style it will behave like dynamic available space so when keyboard opens up the available space will be reduced from full height to available height after keyboard opened.

Here, I don't think you will need keyboard avoiding view as input is already on the top of the screen.

You can also **try the below codebase** to make it work:

**Eg**.

```
<KeyboardAvoidingView style={{ flex: 1, minHeight: Dimensions.get('screen').height }}>
```

**Explanation**:
here I have removed the behaviour property as input is already on top so no need to handle the avoiding view and added minHeight to device height so that it won't change the available space when keyboard opens up.